# Getting Total Lines of Code Altered Over Past Month Including All Branches?

Tags: git, github

In GitHub (or, using just git), is there a way to get the total number of additions/deletions to a repository over the past month **inclusive** of all branches (not just master)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you could try this:

```
git diff --shortstat "@{1 month ago}"
```